# Heroku detected Rails is not set to serve static_assets

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, redirect, heroku, rack

How come every time I "git push heroku" it says this (the middle part)? It works, just curious.

```
-----> Heroku receiving push
-----> Ruby/Rails app detected
```

---

---

```
-----> Detected Rails is not set to serve static_assets
       Installing rails3_serve_static_assets... done
-----> Configure Rails 3 to disable x-sendfile
       Installing rails3_disable_x_sendfile... done
-----> Configure Rails to log to stdout
       Installing rails_log_stdout... done
```

---

---

```
-----> Gemfile detected, running Bundler version 1.0.7
       All dependencies are satisfied
-----> Compiled slug size is 6.6MB
-----> Launching... done, v101
```

Comment: It think it means that Heroku has detected that your Rails app is not set to serve static assets, even though `serve_static_assets` is set to `false`. To re-enable static assets it installs `rails3_serve_static_assets`.

Comment: How would I make it not do this? i.e. where would I set it to true?

Comment: Sorry, I don't know. From this is seems Heroku wants to serve static assest no matter your setting. There is a setting `config.serve_static_assets` in `config/environments/production.rb`, but it's already set to `false`...

Comment: Just try setting serve_static_assets to true, to avoid the message. Heroku seems to be stubborn about it.

Comment: If it ain't broke, don't fix it

Comment: Which Heroku statck is this on?

Answer (score 2):

config.serve_static_assets can be set to true in the config/application.rb or config/environments/production.rb